# PHP Forms: Posting to an absolute path using a captcha

Tags: php, forms, email, captcha

I use an e-mail marketing company to send HTML e-mail and I use an absolute path in the post and include hidden variables which they use to process the form. I would like to add a captcha, but don't know how to do it. All of the php captcha options use the post to post to a process.php page. How do I do that and still post absolutely to the e-mail marketing company including the hidden variables?

Comment: Ca we assume with 'absolute path' you mean a url?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you currently just set your form's `action` attribute to the marketing company's url:

```
<form action="http://marketingsite.com/form.php" method="post">
```

...but now, you want to validate the data before sending it.

One option is to validate your data within your own website's `process.php`, and then use `cURL` to post the data to the marketing site.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

`cURL` is usually included when you install PHP. It is used to read and send data to other people's webpages. You can pick which data you want to post, then use `cURL` to post it.

```
<?php
//  validate the CAPTCHA code first

//  This array will hold the data that you are POSTing to the marketing site
$post = array();

//  validate the other fields here, and add the relevant ones to an array. e.g.:
if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 4 && strlen($_POST['name'] < 20)) {
    $post['name'] = $_POST['name'];
}
if(strlen($_POST['hiddenfield'] != 0)) {
    $post['hiddenfield'] = $_POST['hiddenfield'];
}
//  ...

$curl = curl_init(); 

//  post the data to this url:
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,'http://marketingsite.com/form.php'); 

//  This indicates that we are going to post some data:
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,true); 

//  Post this data:
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post); 

//  If your script successfully sent the data, && if http://marketingsite.com/form.php returned a 200 code 
//      (i.e.: not a 404 error or something)
if(curl_exec($curl) && curl_getinfo($curl,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 200) {
    echo 'Thank you for submitting your data';
} else {
    echo 'Your data was not submitted :( ';
}
curl_close($curl); 
?>
```

This will post everything you choose, including hidden fields or other fields that you want to add.

There are other options that you can set up too. You can try to read the receiving webpage and echo that content back onto your site. You can learn more about `cURL` and `PHP` here:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php